# How to get sound to work?

Tags: sound

I am on a iMac OS X running Ubuntu 16.04 and I can't get my headphones and speakers to work. I don't know what to try because I am new to Linux.
The result of `sudo lspci | grep Audio` is

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Turks/Whistler HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6000 Series]
```

And `alsamixer` doesn't help.

Also found that the speakers work fine when not using headphones. Headphone only problem.

Comment: More information would be nice. What sort of mac? What's the output of  `sudo lspci  | grep Audio` ?

Comment: Something you can try is to use the `alsamixer` command in a terminal - "MM" under a column or a column set to 0 will indicate that it is muted. (The `m` key will unmute, and arrow keys do the rest of movement within the program). However, this information should line up with what's available in the GUI, i.e. upper right hand corner volume controls, near the time, on your desktop.